# Is it possible to set git up to have default fetch/push locations that are different, and if so, how?

Tags: git, version-control

I understand that I can use 'git push -u [repo] [br]' to make [repo] the default upstream for branch [br].

What I would like to do is set things up so that 'git fetch' fetches changes from one repo for a given branch, and 'git push' pushes changes to a different repo for that same branch.

So far reading the man pages and searching here hasn't turned anything up.

The reason I would like to do this is because there is an open source project (not hosted on GitHub), and I have created a fork of it (on GitHub), and would like to by default pull from the open source project, and by default push to my private fork.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See `remote.<name>.pushurl` in [git config](http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/v1.7.10.1/git-config.html). `remote.<name>.url` sets your push and fetch location, but if you also specify `remote.<name>.pushurl`, then the former is used only for fetches and the latter for pushes.

Comment: I see. A bit confusing since I normally think of the remote name as being the source/destination.

Answer (score 0):

The `git remote` command has a `--push` flag when calling `set-url`

`git remote set-url --push <name> <url>`

For example:

`git remote set-url --push origin git@github.com:username/repo/project.git`